# Binance Futures API Giving wrong quarterly price

Tags: php, api, binance

I'm doing some work for a client and need to create a line graph of historical premium between BTCUSD and BTCUSD Quarterly.

https://testnet.binancefuture.com/fapi/v1/premiumIndex?symbol=BTCUSDT
https://testnet.binancefuture.com/fapi/v1/premiumIndex?symbol=BTCUSDT_210326

However when I hit these 2 urls I get almost exactly the same price, but when I view the March 2021 on the Binance platform it does show a much higher price.

Has anybody come across this and is there a way to calculate what the future price is actually trading at.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I see you are using `testnet.` subdomain. Could it be these are only testing numbers

Comment: I would recommend that you contact the API provider instead. Even if someone here have knowledge about their API's, they might not necessarily know if they have made any recent changes, or if there is some issue with your account (like missing settings etc.) It could even be a temporary bug.

Comment: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#general-info this url says to use the testnet url. All the figures are right apart from the Quaterly futures prices, so i'm wondering if theres something in the API i'm missing like another API call to get the "premium" and then multiply price by that premium to get the actual Quarterly price